# Display multiple output in csv using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

```
$s3list = Get-S3Bucket  | Select-Object BucketName, CreationDate

foreach ($item in $s3list) {
    $s3bucket = $item.bucketname
    Get-S3BucketTagging -BucketName $s3bucket
}
```

The above code is incorrect.

`Get-S3Bucket` creates two objects, they are `BucketName` and `CreationDate`.

`Get-S3BucketTagging` also creates two objects `Key` and `Value`.

How do I write this to display in CSV file so the output looks like:
[image]

*Each BucketName associated with multiple keys and values.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your data so that one object at the output will be one row in your CSV. Since you have one object of `S3Bucket` and several corresponding `S3BucketTagging` objects, you can run foreach loop against the latter and create one custom object containing data from both.

```
$s3list = Get-S3Bucket  | Select-Object BucketName, CreationDate

foreach ($item in $s3list) {
    $s3bucket = $item.bucketname
    $s3tags=Get-S3BucketTagging -BucketName $s3bucket
    foreach ($tag in $s3tags) {
        new-object PSObject -property @{
            "BucketName"=$item.bucketname;
            "CreationDate"=$item.creationdate;
            "Key"=$tag.key;
            "Value"=$tag.value
        } # this puts the newly created object to output
    }
}
```

You can use the output of this script blick to pipe into `Export-CSV` with required parameters. Note though, the two leftmost columns won't be "grouped", so that subsequent rows would hvae blanks, you'll have to post-process the CSV.